# ChangeNotifierProvider isn't listening

Tags: flutter, provider, changenotifier

I am attempting to share a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to my `main.dart`, however the value never gets updated.
How it works

> 1. `main.dart` uses `ChangeNotifierProvider` to get an instance of the class `Location()`
> 2. `main.dart` routes to the `location_login.dart` page where a string in `Location()` class is set.
> 3. The instance of `Location()` should update in `main.dart` but it **DOES NOT**.

Here is the `main.dart`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Location>.value(    <------ CREATE CHANGENOTIFIERPROVIDER
      value: Location(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Location location = Provider.of<Location>(context, listen: false);  <----- LISTEN TO PROVIDER
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider<List<Report>>(
          create: (context) =>
              Collection<Report>(path: '${location.getLocation}/data/reports')  <----- USE PROVIDER STRING IN PATH
              .getUsers(),
          initialData: [],
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => LocationLogin(),
          '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
          '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        },

        // Theme
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Nunito',
          bottomAppBarTheme: BottomAppBarTheme(
            color: Colors.black87,
          ),
          // your customizations here
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `location_login.dart`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Location location = Provider.of<Location>(context, listen: true);
return Scaffold(
  body: TextButton(
          child: Text("Submit",
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 15.sp, color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () {
            location.setLocation('London');              <------- SETTING LOCATION
          }),

    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `location.dart`

```
class Location with ChangeNotifier {
  String place = 'none';

  String get getLocation => place;

  setLocation(String location) {
    place = location;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

To reiterate, the issue is that when I click the button in the `location_login.dart` page to set the location to "London"; it does not update the `ChangeNotifierProvider` with a new instance of the `Location()` class containing "London". Therefore, I can **not** update the path in my `FurtureProvider`. Any ideas of what is going wrong here? I tried to make this as clear as possible but if you don't understand please ask. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not consume the `ChangeNotifierProvider`.
For me below simple implementation work perfectly.

my `main.dart` file code is as below...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'providers/app_provider.dart';
import 'providers/favorites_provider.dart';
import 'providers/comments_provider.dart';
import 'providers/home_provider.dart';
import 'providers/details_provider.dart';
import 'providers/gallery_provider.dart';
import 'providers/chat_provider.dart';
import 'ui/splash.dart';
import 'helper/constants.dart';
import 'ui_user/login.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GalleryProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CommentsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChatProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => HomeProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => DetailsProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FavoritesProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppProvider appProvider, Widget child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          key: appProvider.key,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          navigatorKey: appProvider.navigatorKey,
          title: Constants.appName,
          theme: appProvider.theme,
          home: appProvider.isLogin ==  "0" ? LoginPage() : Splash(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And my app_provider.dart as below...

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../helper/constants.dart';

class AppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  AppProvider() {
    checkTheme();
  }
  String isLogin = "0";
  ThemeData theme = Constants.lightTheme;
  Key key = UniqueKey();
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  void setKey(value) {
    key = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setNavigatorKey(value) {
    navigatorKey = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTheme(value, c) {
    theme = value;
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      prefs.setString("theme", c).then((val) {
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor:
              c == "dark" ? Constants.darkPrimary : Constants.lightPrimary,
          statusBarIconBrightness:
              c == "dark" ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
        ));
      });
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ThemeData getTheme(value) {
    return theme;
  }

  Future<ThemeData> checkTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ThemeData t;
    String r =
        prefs.getString("theme") == null ? "light" : prefs.getString("theme");

    isLogin = prefs.getString("isLogin") == null? "0" : prefs.getString("isLogin");

    if (r == "light") {
      t = Constants.lightTheme;
      setTheme(Constants.lightTheme, "light");
    } else {
      t = Constants.darkTheme;
      setTheme(Constants.darkTheme, "dark");
    }

    return t;
  }
}
```

This solution is working very well for me. Hope this will help you too...